# Datatable being applied to only one table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have multiple tabs on a page that have tables in them having same class and i applied datatables on them, the table is extracted to a partial (using Rails) and filling up dynamically with data from controller, the problem i am facing is that the Datatable is being applied to just the first table that is displayed in the first tab that is active and is not initializing other tables in other tabs.. I am not using the gem for this, just the file..

The things i have tried:

```
$('table.propertytable').each(function(index) {

    $(this).dataTable({
        'bFilter': false,
        'bPaginate': false,
        'bLengthChange': false,
        'info': false,
        'fixedHeader': true
    });
});
```

and this:

```
var datatable = $('table.propertytable').DataTable({
    'bFilter': false,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'info': false,
    'fixedHeader': true
});
```

doesn't seem to work, did someone faced this before..

Comment: We need more information to help! but I'm guessing that those tables are initialize by Jquery, right? Are you using turbolink?

Comment: yes, turbolinks are in rails by default, the tables are initialized with datatable  jquery..

Comment: Try to initialize your tables in turbolink load event.

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima nothing happened, it actually removed the initialization from the table that was working recently.

Comment: The information I gave to you was just a guessing based on the fact that turbolink changes the way javascript load the script. I will need more information about your problem with you want some help! Are you following in your browser the debbuger console to see with javascript is working properly?